# tmux: select pane by a letter after `prefix q`, instead of a number

Tags: tmux

I know I can select a timux pane directly by <kbd>prefix q</kbd>. I modified this default binding to `bind / display-panes \; select-pane -t :` in my config.

What I want is to have the selection not by the numbers that overlay each pane after <kbd>C /</kbd>, but by letters, say homerow HJKL or some sort of combination thereof.

Comment: I would love this as well, did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: I have not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my config, I have this:

```
#switch panels
bind k selectp -U # switch to panel Up
bind j selectp -D # switch to panel Down 
bind h selectp -L # switch to panel Left
bind l selectp -R # switch to panel Right
```

so that I can `prefix + h/j/k/l` to switch panel.

Comment: This I also have. If I have, say 5 horizontal splits, getting from 2 pane to 5th will take three presses <kbd>prefix j</kbd>. Alternatively, <kbd>prefix q</kbd> shows momentarily pane number overlays, and I can select the needed pane immediately. But this produces number overlays, I would like letter overlays.